# How to set the state after editing an array entry

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created an edit function for entries of an array. From the `edit` component I pass a object with a function to my main component. This object has an id which determines which object it is in the database. By doing a AJAX `put` request I post the object/entry to my database. This goes well and so the next step is to update my current state so I don't need a refresh to change the data. This goes right I guess, but, the way it works is not that good.

```
editIcecream(product) {

    product.price = Number(product.price)

    fetch( '/api/icecreams/' + product.id, {
        method:'put',
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(product)
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })

    .then( data => {
        /* Updating the state */
        var array = this.state.icecreams.filter((item) => {
            return item.id !== data.id
        });

        this.setState(() => ({
            icecreams: array.concat(product)
        }))

    }); 

}
```

So the main problem is that I am doing a filter to remove the current entry, with data before the edit, and then concat the product to the array to add the product I just edited again. But, this will resulting in a new order which is not something I would like to have. So when I got 2 items with an id of 1 and 6, and I edit 1, the new order will become 6 and after that the edited one with id of 1. So how can I sort the array or re-write this function that the order of the array will not be changed?

I've tried to add this:

```
this.state.icecreams.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.id - b.id
});
```

but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Have a thorough read [of this React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). Your `setState` calls above **must** use the callback form.

Comment: Your using lamda function. Use data instead of this. This is not what you xpected to work if you use lamda function

Comment: On a phone so can't double check, but shouldn't this just be this.setState({ icecreams: array.concat(product) })?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the array in this way:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    icecreams: prevState.icecreams.map(item => item.id === data.id? product: item)
}))
```

What it will do is, it will maintain the order or each item. Whenever it will find the item with the id you have edited, it will return the updated one otherwise the same item.

Another main point is, you need to use `prevState` inside setState updater function. Check the **[doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)** for more explanation, why we need to use that.

Check this snippet:

```js
let arr = [{a:1, id:1}, {a:2, id:2}, {a:3, id:3}];

let update = (id, newData) => {
   return arr.map(el => el.id==id? newData: el);
}

let newArr = update(2, {a:5, id:5});

console.log('newArr = ', newArr);
```

Comment: Hmm. The above code doesn't seem to work for some reason. The state does not update, but get no error or something.

Comment: @Gijsberts have you check `console.log(this.state.icecreams)` in render method, let me know the result because this should work.

Comment: @MayankShukla hmm I guess I made a typo or something, it works now. Thanks for your help and info!